# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel-5.6 with Ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a route

```
Route::post('/subscription/save','SubscriptionController@save')->name('sub.save');
```

and its the only route no duplication, I am submitting by Ajax from this code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
$('.btn-ok').click(function(){            

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'card_type':$('#card_type').val(),
                'card_number':$('#card_number').val(),
                'expiry':$('#expiry').val(),
                'cvv':$('#cvv').val(),
                'name':$('#name').val(),
                'surname':$('#surname').val(),
                'address1':$('#address1').val(),
                'address2':$('#address2').val(),
                'province':$('#province').val(),
                'city':$('#city').val(),
                'country':$('#country').val(),                
                'box_id':$('#sub_box_id').val()
            } ,
            url: "{{route('sub.save')}}",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

If I log data variable in console it appears fine. Here is my controller function

```
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
     $Subscription=new Subscription;
     return $request;
    }
```

I tried return request but I get this 405 Error again n again

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 No message
```

What am I doing wrong?

========================
I have updated the post, I am using CSRF in header

Comment: check csrf token. also try 'method' instead of 'type'

Comment: Run `php artisan routes` to make sure the route is registered correctly. Also check if the URL generated is actually the correct one and doesn't have any strange escaping in it

Comment: let me write an answer for you.

Comment: can you check the request details in your browser console's network tab?

Comment: use crud actions like `create` instead of `save`
then 

`Route::post('/subscription/, `Scubscription@create`)` 

even better use resource:  

`Route::resource('/subscriptions', 'SubscriptionsController')`;

If you have time watch these two videos to better design your API

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI

https://vimeo.com/17785736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudassir You are getting this error either you are trying to use blade syntax `{{}}` in `.js` file

Either use an absolute path or use this syntax inside `blade file`.

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function(){            

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'card_type':$('#card_type').val(),
                'card_number':$('#card_number').val(),
                'expiry':$('#expiry').val(),
                'cvv':$('#cvv').val(),
                'name':$('#name').val(),
                'surname':$('#surname').val(),
                'address1':$('#address1').val(),
                'address2':$('#address2').val(),
                'province':$('#province').val(),
                'city':$('#city').val(),
                'country':$('#country').val(),                
                'box_id':$('#sub_box_id').val()
            } ,
            url: "/subscription/save",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

Secondly, you are using the `POST` method make sure to add CSRF token in the request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou Adnan I am using CSRF Token secondly route works , though i changed it to absolute path still i get the same error

Comment: @MalikMudassar is there route group or prefixes you are using?

Comment: single route, no group or prefix.

Comment: @MalikMudassar are u serving files using apache or `php artisan serve`?

Comment: apache server, php 7.2 laravel 5.6

Comment: @MalikMudassar please post your Base url too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173534/discussion-between-malik-mudassar-and-adnan-mumtaz).

Answer (score 2):

[**405 ERROR - Method Not Allowed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)

If its POST method Laravel needs [CSRF value to Prevent Cross-site request forgeries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-introduction)

You can simply add `_token` in your AJAX

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

'_token':token,
```

---

Final code

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        '_token':token,
        'card_type':$('#card_type').val(),
        'card_number':$('#card_number').val(),
        'expiry':$('#expiry').val(),
        'cvv':$('#cvv').val(),
        'name':$('#name').val(),
        'surname':$('#surname').val(),
        'address1':$('#address1').val(),
        'address2':$('#address2').val(),
        'province':$('#province').val(),
        'city':$('#city').val(),
        'country':$('#country').val(),                
        'box_id':$('#sub_box_id').val()
    } ,
    url: "{{route('sub.save')}}",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add **/subscription/save** to **$except array** in **VerifyCsrfToken Middleware** then it have not need to define **csrf token**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [

          "/subscription/save"

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not excluded this url from CSRF middleware. Your application expects it to be a normal `POST` method with a CSRF token but you are sending an AJAX request which by default doesn't know about CSRF token. Quick solution would be to exclude this URL from `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. You would do something like this;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'subscription/save',
    ];
}
```

Or you can configure AJAX to send CSRF token in header `X-CSRF-TOKEN` with each request. This is more secure and better way to do AJAX requests and this way it would handle all AJAX requests instead of adding every url to `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

**In header**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**In script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem of CSRF token because you are not sending any token to the backend. You can use meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Also you can do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your header

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Add this in your ajax request

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
```